# Roots of a complex polynomial (v.2)

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

From this post :
[Roots of a complex polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88065/roots-of-a-complex-polynomial)

Let $f(z)=a_0+⋯+a_nz^n$ be a complex polynomial with $a_j=α_j+iβ_j$ (with $α_j,β_j∈R$). Let $P(z)=α_0+⋯+α_nz^n$ and $Q(z)=β_0+⋯+β_nz^n$, so that $f(z)=P(z)+iQ(z)$. Assume that all the roots of $f$ are in the half-plane $\Im z>0$.

How do you prove that all the roots of $P$ and $Q$ are real?

My attempt : If $r$ a complex root of $P$ or $Q$, then $f(r)=\pm \overline{f(\bar{r})}$ but then I have the intuition that this leads to contradict the fact that all roots of $f$ are $\Im z>0$

Is there a way to solve it using this idea ?

Comment: I have no idea whether your attempt will work.  However, my **guess** is that your attempt is in fact the intended solution.

Comment: the idea is that $2i(P(\bar z)Q(z)-P(z)Q(\bar z))=|f(z)|^2-|f(\bar z)|^2$ and the fact that the condition on the roots of $f$ implies $|f(z)| < |f(\bar z)|, \Im z>0$ (why?), so RHS is either strictly negative or strictly positive for complex non-real $z$, so LHS cannot be zero!

Comment: @Conrad wait... is this identiy well-known ? Could you show it as it doesn't seem trivial for me ?

Comment: defining $f^*(z)=f(\bar z)$ one has that: $\bar f=P^*-iQ^*, f^*=P^*+iQ^*, \bar f^*=P-iQ$ so using that $|f(z)|^2-|f(\bar z)|^2=f\bar f-f^*\bar {f^*}$ the identity follows - this holds in general for any polynomial; the other part which is the essence in this case follows from the decomposition in linear factors and the (geometrically obvious) fact that $|z-w| < |\bar z-w|$ for $\Im z, \Im w >0$